# g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mt'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, g++

I'm trying to compile a program from source. In an OpenSuse 12.1 chroot the program compiles fines, but in an OpenSuse leap 42.1 chroot I get the following error:

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mt'
```

I've searched (both on here and on google) but couldn't find much information on the -mt flag. What is this '-mt' flag?

Comment: Cannot be found in the [GNU GCC options summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary). May be it was meant for a different compiler?

Comment: First thing that pops into my mind is the MS Visual Studio /MT multithreaded, static linking compiler option. Spinning up an openSUSE 12.2, closest I have easily at hand, I can find nothing in gcc.

Comment: It seems like it's an old option, see: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/IA_002d64-Options.html. Can it safely be replaced by the pthread flag? That one still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This flag is used to compile and link multi-threaded applications.

With `gcc` you should use `-pthread` for both compiling and linking, no `-lpthread` is necessary.

When compiling `-pthread` sets the necessary macros, when linking it links in the required libraries.